Having issues with electron-builder when using extraResources and extraFiles
Environment:
node --version: v18.19.1
package.json:
"dependencies": {
"@electron/remote": "^2.1.2",
"@voerkai18n/runtime": "^2.1.5",
"@voerkai18n/vue": "^2.1.5",
"@vue/cli-shared-utils": "^5.0.8",
"bindings": "^1.5.0",
"body-parser": "^1.20.2",
"cnpm": "^9.4.0",
"core-js": "^3.8.3",
"debug": "^4.3.4",
"depd": "^2.0.0",
"ee-first": "^1.1.1",
"electron": "^30.0.1",
"electron-builder": "^24.9.1",
"electron-builder-squirrel-windows": "^24.13.3",
"electron-devtools-installer": "^3.2.0",
"electron-rebuild": "^3.2.9",
"encodeurl": "^2.0.0",
"escape-html": "^1.0.3",
"express": "^4.18.2",
"file-uri-to-path": "^2.0.0",
"finalhandler": "^1.2.0",
"fs": "^0.0.1-security",
"html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
"ip": "^2.0.1",
"is-port-available": "^0.1.5",
"lru-cache": "^8.0.0",
"lzma-native": "^8.0.6",
"merge-descriptors": "^2.0.0",
"ms": "^2.1.3",
"node-machine-id": "^1.1.12",
"node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
"on-finished": "^2.4.1",
"ora": "^8.0.1",
"parseurl": "^1.3.3",
"path": "^0.12.7",
"path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
"pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
"primevue": "^3.49.1",
"qrcodejs2": "^0.0.2",
"rebuild": "^0.1.2",
"semver": "^7.6.0",
"sequelize": "^6.37.1",
"sqlite": "^5.1.1",
"sqlite3": "5.1.6",
"statuses": "^2.0.1",
"typeorm": "^0.3.20",
"unzip-crx-3": "^0.2.0",
"uuidjs": "^5.0.1",
"vue": "^3.4.26",
"vue-router": "^4.0.3",
"ws": "^8.16.0",
"wujie-vue3": "^1.0.22"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.24.1",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.1",
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
"@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
"babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
"electron": "^30.0.1",
"electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.0",
"sass": "^1.32.7",
"sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
"vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.1.1",
"webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
}
Problem:
I was trying to use electron-builder to build my electron app, however encountering problems with static resources bundling.
Codes in vue.config.js:
enter image description here
Project structure:
enter image description here
Then I used npm run electron:build to run the building process, I got this:
enter image description here
It seems that the specific "./lib" directory did'nt went into the resources directory as expected.I also tried using FileSet objects and they did'nt work either.
Also, extraFiles seemed not working either.
I suspect there's something wrong, but as a beginner to electron, I don't know any other way to solve this.

The problem was resolved yesterday.
It was caused by incorrect config format.
There should be an "builderOptions" under the "electronBuilder" dict in vue.config.js, and I accidentally left it out.
